# Laying out bottom-aligned buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a better way to do this, where buttons are bottom aligned on either side of the screen? Important parts are alignParentBottom, which appears to only be available in RelativeLayout, and layout_gravity, which appears to only be available in LinearLayout and its subclasses like TableLayout, of which RelativeLayout is not one.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/list_delete"
                    android:text="@string/list_delete"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/list_save"
                    android:text="@string/list_add"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Android lint is giving me errors like this:

- This TableLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless
- This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
   <RelativeLayout//this will be your parent layout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_delete"
                android:text="@string/list_delete"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_save"
                android:text="@string/list_add"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


</RelativeLayout>
```